# Slow WordPress User Query(s) Over 7000 users

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, lazy-loading

I am almost done building a WordPress website, and the main issue holding up from launching is the very long times it is taking to execute user queries.

I have enabled cacheing in browser, and in php, and gziping, as well as using W3 Total cache plugin, and tried various other caching plugins with marginal success.

Also have raised the timeout time and memory in php.ini and wp-config.

The main page I am having an issue with is http://www.qbhitlist.com/qbhitlist/quarterbacks/ but the home page, and the other two ranking pages are slow as well.

http://www.qbhitlist.com/qbhitlist/rankings/qbhl-top-50/
http://www.qbhitlist.com/qbhitlist/rankings/qbhl-premium-player-rankings/

I understand why (querying over 7000 users) but there is no way around doing that, that I am aware of.

So is there a way to possibly save the main query to a json file, or global array, or lazyload the query after the page has loaded? Or any other solution that would drastically decrease the page load time / improve performance.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The query isn't slow. Collecting and returning the output isn't even slow. (Well, 3 sec, it's not fast, but that's a 4.9 MB HTML document.) Processing it client side is slow. (For me 18 sec.) Whatever you're doing server side to make it faster, you need something smart client side. (Like not downloading and processing all records at once.)

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: I don't know WP, so no. I suggest loading only the data you're showing. WP must have pagers.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the html in a transient. Set the expiration to `0` and delete the transient programmatically every time you update the list, so it gets regenerated.

Sample code:

```
function get_qb_list() {

    $qb_list = get_transient( 'qb_list' );

    if( false === $qb_list ) {

        $qb_list = 'HTML GOES HERE';

        set_transient( 'qb_list', $qb_list, 0 );
    }

    return $qb_list;

}
```

Transients are stored in the wp options table. Read more about the Transients API [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. You should not dump all that data on a single page at once like that.

Even if you got to reduce the load time and put the site live, you would have to many queries hitting the database as soon as the number of concurrent users goes up. My guess is that the database would not handle such traffic.

Try to save the query in an intermediary table that you have more control over and get the data in bits. Display the first 50 items then link to the next 50 items use ajax or regualar pagintation without ajax and the load time will come down and you will not have issues when the site is live.

Comment: I am not really sure how to do this...

This is my code as is. http://pastebin.com/QuzKNWyq

Comment: Here is the modified code http://pastebin.com/EZifuEfz, a few lines that will make the page load quicker and will be more elegant. Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Who_Parameter so as to know what need to filtered from database for the case of membership.

Comment: This kinda works, but breaks the dataTables.



I was able to get the ajax working, but now it loads all the players on the same page.

I seem to be using the correct options to set page length, and even set an option to only display 100 total players in the json array. 

Yet its pulling all of them.
Any advice on this?

http://pastebin.com/byMtYEz1 

Any help is greatly appreciated